# How to find atleast one build is in progress in Jenkins?

Tags: build, hudson, jenkins, command-line-interface

I am using Jenkins with tomcat. I use jenkins cli from java class to create job and to build. **I want to check, is any build is progress**. Is there anyway to do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following XPath expression will give you the total number of busy executors on the master and all slaves, if it's > 0, you have a job running:

`http://[jenkins_server]/computer/api/xml?xpath=/computerSet/busyExecutors/text()`

You can connect to your server from Java via HTTP and query it.